# if Null in DB, how to show blank in text box in the view

Tags: c#-3.0

First I want to check that value is null or not, and if the value that is coming from the DB is null, then I want to make it as blank so that it will not show that null word in Text box in the view. Is there any need to use isnullorempty function?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: i checked but didn't get the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code for web form

```
showTextBox=value==null?" ":value;
```

Try bellow code for Razor view in MVC

```
model => model.value==null?" ":model.value
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the data from the DB, it often comes with format of NULLABLE.

This gives you two values and never brings you the word 'null' or you can ask for example if the name of the column is 'student':

```
textbox.Text=student.value!=null? student.value.tostring():"";
```

This bring you the value or a blank textbox.